# Fill in the blank: "One problem invites _____"

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

In the Thai Cloze Test, why is "another" the correct answer for "One problem invites _____"?

Here is the question:

> Problems that teenagers are faced with today are multifarious but interrelated in many cases. One problem invites **(another/others/the other/other/the others)**, then leads to more problems.

The answers is **another**. Why "another" is correct?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to answer this question- from a syntactic/semantic point of view, and by treating this as a reference to an English idiom.

The English idiom is "[one thing leads to another](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/one-thing-leads-to-another)", which in itself suggests that a chain of events takes place, generally outside the control of the people involved.

Looking at the syntax, the word must be a pronoun or noun. This rules out [other](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/other) because it is a determiner: you can talk about "other problems" or "other things" but you can't use "other" on its own.

You can only use "the other" when there are only two possibilities- for example hands... "His phone was in one hand and a pack of cigarettes was in the other". As it states in the first sentence, there are young people face a lot more than two problems.

"the others" would mean "all of the other problems": this does not work because the speaker subsequently refers to "more problems" that follow on from the second one.

[another](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/another) can be a determiner or pronoun meaning "one more person or thing or an extra amount". This meaning would work, and the pronoun form would fit syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

"Other" is usually used to describe something which is distinct from something previously mentioned.  "Another" is similar, in that it refers to something previously mentioned, but it suggests one of the same *type*.  For example:

"I ate Italian food and tried many things other than pasta dishes."  -- Dishes which are distinctly *different* from pasta dishes

"I loved their breadsticks so much I had another."  -- I ate an *additional* breadstick of the same kind.

Another is correct here, because we're talking about a problem not unlike the previous mentioned.